# Java rotating filenames for backup

Tags: java, database, file, jdbc

This question is related to Java development.
I am using an embedded jdbc:derby database in a desktop app which I wish to have the user backup whenever they wish (or maybe even automate it).

Problem:
Cannot/Do not desire to overwrite existing db backup file; rather I would like to keep x number of backups by changing the name in a predictable sequence. The database contains only a single table.

I appreciate any and all efforts to assist me!! Thank you, in advance! :)

What I have so far is:

```
public static boolean backupDatabase() throws SQLException {
    status = false;
    f = new File("backup.db");
    n = new File("backup.dbold");
    status = f.exists();
    if (status){
        f.renameTo(n); 
    }
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        status = statement.execute("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE(null,'TREATMENTS','./backup.db',null,null,null)");
        System.out.println("Database Backed Up Successfully.");
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println ("SQL Error: " + err.getMessage());
    }
    statement.closeOnCompletion();
    connection.close();
    return status;
}
```

[UPDATE]

I have been at this for most of the day. The following code runs without error and as expected. If anyone is interested in the fix (for future reference) here it is -- along with some other methods that perform essential DataBase Operations:

```
    package org.redbrick.medright;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import static java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.*;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.time.LocalDateTime;
    import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;
    import java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    /**
     *
     * @author RedBrick
     */
    public class DatabaseOps {

      private static int rowsAffected;
      private static boolean status;
      private static boolean success;
      private static Connection con;
      private static Statement statement;
      private static CallableStatement freeze;
      private static CallableStatement backup;
      private static CallableStatement unfreeze;
      private static CallableStatement checkDB;

      private static Connection connection;
      private static Path currentPath = null;
      private static Path newPath = null;
      private static LocalDateTime now;
      private static TemporalUnit minutes;
      private static String filetime;

      public static boolean runDbaseChecks (Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
          // statement = connection.createStatement ();
          checkDB = connection.prepareCall ( "VALUES SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_CHECK_TABLE('APP', 'TREATMENTS')" );
          checkDB.execute ();
          checkDB.close ();
          System.out.println ( "Table Treatements checked Successfully." );
        } catch ( SQLException err ) {
          System.out.println ( "SQL Error: " + err.getMessage () );
        }
        return success;
      }

      public static boolean backupDatabase (Connection connection) throws SQLException {

        try {
          freeze = connection.prepareCall ( "CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_FREEZE_DATABASE()" );
          freeze.execute ();
          freeze.close ();

          backup = connection.prepareCall ( "CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE(?)" );
          backup.setString ( 1, "./DBaseBackups" );
          backup.execute ();
          backup.close ();

          unfreeze = connection.prepareCall ( "CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_UNFREEZE_DATABASE()" );
          unfreeze.execute ();
          unfreeze.close ();
        } catch ( Exception err ) {
          System.out.println ( "Error backing up database " + err.getMessage () + err.getCause () );
        }
        return status;
      }

      public static boolean backupDatabaseTable (Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
          status = false;
          currentPath = Paths.get ( "./backup.db" );
          status = Files.exists ( currentPath );
          if ( status ) {

            now = LocalDateTime.now ();
            now = now.truncatedTo ( ChronoUnit.MINUTES );
            filetime = now.toString ();
            newPath = Paths.get ( "./backup. " + filetime + ".db" );
            try {
              Files.move ( currentPath, newPath, REPLACE_EXISTING );
              System.out.println ( "DBase Backup File Successfully Moved" );
            } catch ( IOException ex ) {
              Logger.getLogger ( DatabaseOps.class.getName () ).log ( Level.SEVERE, null, ex );
            }
          } else {
            statement = connection.createStatement ();
            status = statement.execute ( "CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE(null,'TREATMENTS','./backup.db',null,null,null)" );
            System.out.println ( "Database Table Backed Up Successfully." );
          }
        } catch ( SQLException err ) {
          System.out.println ( "SQL Error: " + err.getMessage () );
        }
        statement.closeOnCompletion ();
        return status;
      }
      public static boolean restoreDatabaseTable (Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    try {
      statement = connection.createStatement ();
      status = statement.execute ( "CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_IMPORT_TABLE (null,'TREATMENTS','./backup.db',null,null,null,0)" );
      System.out.println ( "Database Table Restored Successfully." );
    } catch ( SQLException err ) {
      System.out.println ( "SQL Error: " + err.getMessage () );
    }
    statement.closeOnCompletion ();
    return status;
  }

  public static boolean clearDatabaseTable (Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    try {
      statement = connection.createStatement ();
      rowsAffected = statement.executeUpdate ( "DELETE FROM TREATMENTS" );
      System.out.println ( "Database Table Treatements Cleared Successfully." );

    } catch ( SQLException err ) {
      System.out.println ( "SQL Error: " + err.getMessage () );
    }
    statement.closeOnCompletion ();
    return status;
  }

}
```

Comment: Why not just have your Java code disconnect from the database object, then use Java file operations to copy the live database file to a backup folder with a filename which includes a date and timestamp?

Comment: Please [don't use the `File` class anymore](http://java7fs.wikia.com/wiki/Why_File_sucks). It's outdated and uninformative. Use the `Files` class instead.

Comment: @Bobulous -- good suggestion! Thank you.

Comment: @RealSkeptic -- Thanks for the warning! :) Not too difficult to tell that I am a green-horn when it comes to Java! lol

Comment: I'm not sure how the lower portion of the code got out of alignment...